# What is the function of mutex locks as a struct member of C structs

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, mutex

I have an assignment that includes a Plane struct and it includes a `pthread_mutex_t` and a `pthread_cond_t` fields. However, I cannot understand what happens when we lock this lock or wait for this cond.

For example:

```
void* landingPlane(void *ID){
  int planeID = (int) ID;
  plane temp;
  temp.ID = planeID;
  temp.requestTime = time(NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init(&(temp.mutex), NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&(temp.cond), NULL);
  planesArray[planeID] = temp;
  int emergency_id;

  pthread_mutex_lock(&runway_mutex); // this is a global mutex, I know how it works

  pthread_mutex_lock(&planesArray[planeID].mutex);

  // critical section

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&planesArray[planeID].mutex);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&runway_mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
```

What is the point of locking the mutex lock inside plane?

Comment: Frankly I don't see a point in this mutex, as it is local and unique to this function. So there is no way any other thread can acquire/wait on it.

Comment: This assignment may be setting you up for a follow-up where it does make sense to have that mutex.

Comment: Re, "...as a member of a struct." The purpose of locking and unlocking a mutex is to ensure that different threads all have a consistent view of some collection of shared data. It makes sense to keep the mutex close to the data that it protects. E.g., if the data all are members of a struct, then it makes sense for the mutex to be a member of the same struct.

Comment: @SolomonSlow so if I put them in an array, then it makes sense right? Other threads can reach via a plane's ID value?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably a mistake.

Likely, the `runway_mutex` was supposed to protect the introduction or removal of planes to and from the array while the individual plane mutexes were supposed to protect the data in a particular plane.

But this is a pretty complex pattern to get right and, obviously, you definitely wouldn't hold the `runway_mutex` while you manipulate the individual planes nor would you initialize the object mutex *inside the array* without holding any locks.

It's hard to say without seeing code like the code that adds planes to the array.